# HTML syntax highlighting not displaying correctly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

This request is about the syntax highlighting of source code on Stack Overflow.

When HTML attributes contains characters such as `>`, it creates an issue in the syntax highlighting.

Here is a sample of Angular code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717268/4927984) that generates the problem:

[image]

As you can see, there are several problems. For example, the `>` operator in `ng-if` is interpreted as the end of the `<div>`.

**Can we ignore characters such as `>` between `"` and `'` in HTML syntax highlighting?**

Comment: Syntax highlighting is handled by the [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) library, so you'll need to file a bug with them.

Comment: See the section in the answer titled "How do I report a bug or request a new language?"